# Do I have to make data private?

Tags: c++, coding-style, private, public

I know that data in a class should be private then use getter and setter to read/modify them. But isn't it very troublesome compare to using `student.scores.push_back(100)` directly which saves a member function.

```
class Student {
public:

    void addToScores(int inScore) {

        scores.push_back(inScore);
    }

private:

    vector<int> scores;
}
```

In short I'm curious what people actually do in practice, always strictly private data with getter and setter?

Comment: Try to design your class interface before you consider what kinds of data members your class might have. Then you won't have to ask this question.

Comment: No one is forced to write decent code.  Trust me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of member functions is to expose an interface. There is no need to make getters and setters, or other trivial functions, to simply move the interfaces already implemented by members to an aggregate container object.

If the client of `Student` should be allowed to manipulate `scores` however they want, you should make `scores` a public member and access it the easy way. If it should be a stack with only `push`, `pop`, and `top`, then use the `std::stack` interface adaptor. If only `push_back` should be allowed, then you might implement `addToScores`. But if the only client is you, and you're not worried about other parts of the `std::vector` interface being abused, there's really no point in implementing a new interface.

Every interface within a program should be thoughtfully designed. Adding slapdash interfaces as a habit because standard interfaces (including the C++ default assignment operator) are "dangerous" isn't necessarily a good habit.

Answer (score 2):

In practice people use classes to define new data types with new semantics that are independent of their data-members. Neither accessors nor public data members are used, but instead member functions are provided that perform the tasks relevant to the new data-type, while maintaining invariants on the data-members.

Of course, sometimes people write classes that are just aggregates of data, with no additional semantics. In this case, a `struct` filled with public members is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

One of the basic reasons for using Get/Set methods is controlling input type besides data encapsulation.

If you do not want to take some specific input types, let say you may not want a score outside the bounds of [0,100] interval, then you can check this condition in the Set method so that library user can not make an illogical operation.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a simple read/write, you do not really have to make the data private. But if there are validations/conditions that you need to do on the data being read/written, it would make sense for it to be private.